# Crash while selecting row in component 1 in uipickerview in iOS 6

Tags: iphone, uipickerview, ios6

I had an application which was working fine till iOS 5.1. But recently with iOS 6 it has started giving crash when I try to select a row in a component programmatically. Following is my code:

```
UIPickerView *pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 40, 320, 216)];
pickerView.delegate=self;
pickerView.dataSource=self;
pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator=YES;
[pickerView setTag:10];
//[pickerView selectRow:0 inComponent:0 animated:YES];
int index1 = [arrHours indexOfObject:[arrTitle objectAtIndex:0]];
int index2 = [arrMins indexOfObject:[arrTitle objectAtIndex:1]];

[actionSheet addSubview:pickerView];
[pickerView selectRow:index1 inComponent:0 animated:YES];
[pickerView selectRow:index2 inComponent:1 animated:YES];
[pickerView release];
```

It runs fine when I try to select row in component 0 but I get crash when I try to select row in component 1.

Comment: try printing the array .check if the  datasource array is null or not?

Comment: yes checking the data helped me. I have added my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok found the error on debugging. The problem was because of 00 in the data. Earlier framework was converting it to 0 by itself but in new sdk (ios6) it started producing error when I was considering 00 as 0.